# Where can I find the instructions for the crane on the back page of Lego Juniors: Construction (10667)

Tags: instructions, juniors

Where can I find the instructions for the crane on the back page of Lego Juniors: Construction (10667), as pictured.

[image: Back page of 10667 kit]

I tried contacting Lego Support who replied unhelpfully with:

*We currently have over 3300 building instructions available online on LEGO.com/service under Building Instructions. They’re really easy to find: You can search by set number, keyword, play theme or launch year.*

Comment: The 'Find more building instructions online' description under the alternative model is misleading, I tried looking at LEGO.com/Juniors and I couldn't find _more_ instructions, only the ones that came with the set.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I rebuilt the model as best as I could in Lego Digital Designer using only parts from that particular set.

There were a few parts where I couldn't actually find a piece in that set so I used a replacement part that exists in the set.

[image]

[**LDD File**](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cd6k5zg80v919aj/10667%20Alt%20Model.lxf?dl=0)

**[PDF Instructions + Part List](http://issuu.com/ambo100/docs/10667_alternative_model_instruction)**

Answer (score 4):

I think LEGO has got you fooled here - they do not mention that the pictured model has specific alternate building instructions, they just mention that there are a lot of building instructions online. Pretty sad of course and I agree they do make you think this set has other building instructions for the pictured model.

I've looked at LEGO/service, BrickSet, Brickpedia, BrickInstructions.com and nowhere does anyone list an alternative model with instructions for this set.

Answer (score 1):

The Lego website makes it hard to find, but it's there. (I found this question while trying to find it in fact.)

1. Search for kit number 10667, which takes you to [the 10667 kit page](http://shop.lego.com/en-US/LEGO-Juniors-Construction-10667)
2. Click the "Building instructions" tab below the image...
3. ...which will reveal a *single link*, "Building instructions". Yes. Clicking that will take you to [a page with a box containing links to five PDFs](http://service.lego.com/BuildingInstructions/10667)
4. The last PDF, labeled **10667 WEB BI** (no cover image), is the one you want. (Here's a link to [the PDF served from Akamai](https://a248.e.akamai.net/cache.lego.com/r/www/r/service/-/media/franchises/juniors/products/bi/web%20bi%2010667.pdf?l.r2=-1102320543) which won't work forever.)